# Should porch roof pitch always match house roof pitch?

Tags: roof, design

This is question about design standards.

I want to build a small patio roof over a side door to our house, which happens to be the main door we use.

I wanted a gabled roof but realized it would only be able to be 8-9 ft wide or less if I were to match the house roof pitch, so I switched to a lean-to style design. That would give me the 12ft wide by 10-12 ft extension that I want, but I would need to go with a 0.5/12 pitch in order to avoid blocking too much of the view.

Now I'm back to considering a gabled roof but at a *different pitch* from the main house roof. That way I can get even more coverage, 14-16 ft and extend out as far as I want, say 12-14ft. This way I get both the coverage and the visibility I want.

**Question:** Is this an extremely non-standard design?

See Diagram below.

In NE Arkansas. We do get snow, but it usually melts away within a day or so, as 3 storms of 3-4 inches each. Plenty of rain though.

[image: Side of house with proposed porch roof illustrated]

Comment: [![roof rake](https://i.stack.imgur.com/in4jG.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/in4jG.jpg)
Sir are you trying to describe this type of roof application where you add only half way up a roof rake of one side?

Comment: [![drawing of roof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MaTfc.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MaTfc.jpg)
So your meaning something like this? Sorry its sloppy I did it quick for you☺

Comment: Know this has been answered a while back, however, worth noting as design ideas are always current and as i came upon, so too others who could use an idea, maybe even a seed.
Notice the point of the original eve end and the vent. If the new porch roof reflected these, create intention, as if the original roof was severed and flattened in response to the attic vent. From there, could spawn other oppertunities.

Answer (score 2):

I think a lower pitch would look fine, and is in fact seems to be a common design choice for a porch. I think the grey metal roof would work better on a low slope roof than asphalt shingles, but won't be cheap.

We have a 3-in-12 pitch roof and have used good quality asphalt shingles. Perhaps I didn't demand the proper underlayment treatment and our house does have inferior roof decking at 3/8" thick plywood, but we have had problems with leaks.  The slightest dip or discontinuity in the roof decking has led to leaks.

Comment: I'm just planning to do 1x4 cross members over 2x6 rafters and screw the metal roof down. Should be quick and cheap, like $2/sqft for materials. Going to have the panels custom made/cut, so maybe I'm underestimating big time. Will get a quote tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

I'm partly inclined to vote to close as decorating advice and or purely opinion.

Main consideration (for me) with gabled/lean-to is what direction you enter from. If the natural flow of water off the roof would dump a sheet of water on you as you enter, gutters become critical. If not, they are less critical.

Many, many examples of porches with different slopes in the architectural history, both vernacular and otherwise.

You could also let your attic vent be inside the porch roof, if you wanted it to match the house roof - indeed, you could extend the house roof at the same level out over the porch area.

Comment: How about I rephrase the question to ask about standards of design? Are there any examples of what I'm suggesting? I.e. is it a design that is ever used? World that put it in line with site standards?